# access twig array value, outside loop

Tags: twig

I want to reuse my twig variable for the loop outside the loop, but I can't! I've tried like this

```
{% set b = '' %}
{% set c = '' %}

{% for i,foo in cout %}
    {% set b = cout[i] %} 
    {{ b }} 
{% endfor %} 

{% for j,bar in efforts %} 
    {% set c = efforts[j] %}
    {{ c }} 
{% endfor %}

{{ b }} {{ c }}
```

But here it's return me the last value of b and c, so I want all value of c and b outside the loop, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're overwriting variable `b & c` in every loop, that's why you see only the last one.

You have to use [`merge`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html) function here.

```
{% set b = [] %}    

{% for i,foo in cout %}
    {% set b = b|merge([cout[i]]) %}  
{% endfor %}
```

As suggested by DarkBee, to output content of `b` array as a string you can use `join` function, iterate through array, or access values by keys or any other function provided by Twig.

Comment: ok thanks, but merge function return me an error :
`The merge filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", got "string" as first argument.`
whenever I change `{% set b = [] %}` it's return error  `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").
`

Comment: Change `{{ b }} ` to something like `{{ b | join(',') }} `

Comment: I've already do that, but I wan't to use array but not string :(
I don't understand when I do `{{ dump(b) }}` it's return the array in console but `{{ b }}` return error

Comment: `{% set b = b ~' '~ count[i] %}`?

Comment: @KahanAm, My bad. I forgot to edit first line of your code. Please see updated answer.